# iTextSharp centering text on page

Tags: itext

I cannot get the text to be centered on the page. What am I doing wrong?  I have tried several ways to get the page with, but none seem to make the text centered on the page.....

```
            BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("C:\\temp\\Certificate12.pdf");
            var pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);

            iTextSharp.text.Rectangle rec2 = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(PageSize.LETTER);

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stream1);

            PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetUnderContent(1);

            canvas.BeginText();
            canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 24);

            string nameText = "First Name Last Name";
            int textWidth = (int)nameText.Length;

            int canvasWidth = (int)canvas.PdfDocument.PageSize.Width;
            float xStart = (canvasWidth / 2) - (textWidth / 2);

            canvas.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, nameText, xStart, pageSize.GetTop(Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(145)), 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you use `ShowTextAligned` with `ALIGN_CENTER`, iTextSharp will center the text for you, so you do not have to deal with the text width at all. You merely need to tell it to center the text on which center point.

Thus, you can center your text on the page like this:

```
BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\calibri.ttf", BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED);

using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(source))
using (PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(dest, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)))
{
    Rectangle pageSize = reader.GetPageSize(1);
    PdfContentByte canvas = stamper.GetUnderContent(1);

    string nameText = "First Name Last Name";

    canvas.BeginText();
    canvas.SetFontAndSize(bf, 24);
    canvas.ShowTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_CENTER, nameText, (pageSize.Left + pageSize.Right) / 2, pageSize.GetTop(Utilities.MillimetersToPoints(145)), 0);
    canvas.EndText();
}
```

Comment: I did exactly what you did, but it is STILL not centered. I don't know how to put an image in here to show you.

Comment: That's weird. The output I receive is centered. I assume you are using a current iTextSharp version. Thus, the only apparent difference is the PDF you use. Please share it to reproduce your issue.